# How to get the text from certain class name if other sibling class exists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I've tried to get the text from `class="eventAwayMinute">57` in every `matchEvent` class (Parent tag)
If a `matchEvent` class contains `class="eventIcon eventIcon_1"`:

```html
<div class="matchEvent">
    <div class="eventHomePlayer">
    </div>
    <div class="eventHomeMinute"></div>
    <div class="eventIcon eventIcon_1"></div>
    <div class="eventAwayMinute">57'</div>
    <div class="eventAwayPlayer">
        George
        <span>(Irakli)</span> </div>
</div>
```

I tried

```
Minutes = [(gm.get_text()).strip() for gm in soup.select('matchEvent , div[class$="eventIcon_1"]')]
```

and it dose not work.

I tried also

```
Minutes = [(gm.get_text()).strip() for gm in soup.select('matchEvent')]
```

But it returns all minutes that exist in every `matchEvent` (There is several `matchEvent` classes in html code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) CSS Selector to check if `matchEvent` has an `eventIcon eventIcon_1` class, and than print the `eventAwayMinute` class:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div class="matchEvent">
    <div class="eventHomePlayer">
    </div>
    <div class="eventHomeMinute"></div>
    <div class="eventIcon eventIcon_1"></div>
    <div class="eventAwayMinute">57'</div>
    <div class="eventAwayPlayer">
        George
        <span>(Irakli)</span> </div>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for tag in soup.select(".matchEvent:has(.eventIcon.eventIcon_1)"):
    print(tag.select_one(".eventAwayMinute").text.strip("'"))
```

Output:

```
57
```

Comment: Thank you. If you dont mind i have one question. Is there possible in one line to get text if there is eventIcon_1 or eventIcon_3 and find text in eventAwayMinute or in eventHomeMinute? Or i should write is for every possible case?

Comment: @GeorgeKatsadze To select multiple values, add a comma `,` in the selector, for example: `soup.select(".matchEvent:has(.eventIcon.eventIcon_1, .eventIcon.eventIcon_3)")` .. `print(tag.select(".eventAwayMinute, eventHomeMinute"))`

Comment: Thank you very much. It was helpfull